# Apex trigger code to create tasks based on custom field value

Tags: apex, trigger, list, tasks

In my custom object "Project" I have a field called "Number_of_Tasks" that I wish to use to create a task list with the specified # of tasks.  So if the value in this field is 3 I want a list of 3 tasks created.  I found the code below and it does not return any errors, but it is not doing anything.  Does this code look right?  If so, is there a setting I need to change to allow the generation of the task list?

```
trigger tasks on Project__c (after insert, after update)  
{
    public List<Project__c> lstProject=new List<Project__c>();
    lstProject=[SELECT id,Number_of_Tasks__c FROM Project__c WHERE id IN:trigger.New];
    public List<Decimal>lstNumber=new List<Decimal>();
    public  List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
    for(Project__c each:lstProject)
    {
        lstNumber.add(each.Number_of_Tasks__c);
    }

    for(Decimal eachNumber:lstNumber)
    {

        for(decimal i = 0; i <eachNumber; i++)
        {   
            Task b = new Task 
            ( 
                Subject='Project Task',  
                Status = 'In progress',
                Priority = 'High'
            );
            TaskList.add(b);
        }
    }
    insert TaskList;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it is not doing anything"? How did you come to that determination? Have you tried setting some checkpoints, or adding some debug statements, and inspecting them (checkpoints or debug logs) via the developer console?

Comment: If you sourced this code from somewhere online, it's a poor model to follow. The Tasks being created don't have `WhoId` or `WhatId` populated, so they're not linked to anything, among a number of other mistakes.

Comment: If you don't have Apex experience, would you consider addressing this objective with Process Builder + Flow? That should be an achievable solution.

Comment: It's not doing anything, as in no task list is being created after entering value for Number of Tasks.

Comment: I copied the answer from what seems like an identical question and they OP said it worked.  I am trying to learn Apex, that's why I'm trying to do this through a trigger.

Comment: Again, it's important to include details about how you came to the conclusion that no Tasks are being inserted. As David's comment and gNerb's answer point out, you aren't setting the `whoId` or `whatId` field, so you wouldn't see the tasks in the related list on your `Project__c` record. If you were to query using the developer console, I bet you'd find that your Tasks are indeed being inserted.

Comment: This also demonstrates the risk with just blindly copy/pasting code you find on the internet. If you don't take the time to understand _why_ a piece of code works, you're setting yourself up for failure. If you haven't done so already, I'd suggest going through the [Developer Beginner Trail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_dev_beginner) over on trailhead to set a good foundation that you can use to support further learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Task> newTasks = new List<Task>();

for (Project__c proj : Trigger.New) {
    for (Integer i = 0; i < proj.Number_of_Tasks__c; i++) {
        newTasks.add(new Task(
            Subject ='Project Task',  
            Status = 'In progress',
            Priority = 'High',
            WhatId = proj.id
        ));
    }

    proj.Number_Of_Tasks__c = 0;
}

insert newTasks;
```

### Notes

- Set the WhatId so that it appears in the related list on the project
- Optionally set the WhoId
- You do not need to query the field on the project. All fields on the
  project should be available in the trigger (with few exceptions)
- You do not need all those lists
- Optionally, reset your number of tasks field to avoid creating duplicate or unwanted tasks. Since this code fires in every update this could get out of control real fast.

Comment: n.b. `WhoId` relates to `Contact` or `Lead`, not the assigned-to Salesforce User. +1 for generous answer.

Comment: I'm a Apex newbie, this task is one I'm trying in an effort to learn Apex, although I'm starting to think it's too advanced for me to learn on.  But if you guys are feeling patient, maybe you can hold my hand through this (if not I understand).  What do you mean by "set the WhatId so that it appears in the related list on the project".  How do I set the WhatId?

Comment: My code shows you how, it's just "whatId = record.Id" The related list is nothing to do with apex. The reason you can't see your tasks is that they are basically getting lost in the system. If you add a value to the whatId they will appear in the related list of tasks for that object (actvities or activity history lists).

Comment: Ah, OK it's working now.  I wasn't sure if you were showing me a generic term or the exact code.  Thanks for the help!  Ideally the due dates on each of the tasks would be set, evenly distributed based on the project duration (End_Date__c-Start_Date__c)/i.  Having some issues getting the math to calculate.  Any tips for this?